# SwiftUI - alternative to if let with a conditional closure

Tags: view, closures, conditional-statements, swiftui, option-type

I'm trying to implement the following in SwiftUI:

```
struct PersonView: View {

    @State private var age: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Just a test")
            if let self.age > 0 {
                Text("Display Age: \(age)")
            } else {
                Text("Age must be greater than 0!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, in SwiftUI, `if let` results in the following error:

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'

So after researching this topic, I came across a recommendation to use `.map` to unwrap the `age` optional.  Thus, I've modified to code within the `VStack` as follows:

```
Text("Just a test")
self.age.map {elem in
    if elem > 0 {
        Text("Display Age: \(elem)")
    } else {
        Text("Age must be greater than 0!")
    }
}
```

Including a conditional within the `.map` closure, however, results in the following errors at the line calling the `VStack`:

> ' (ViewBuilder.Type) -> (C0, C1) -> TupleView<(C0, C1)>' requires that '()' conform to 'View'
>
> Type '()' does not conform to protocol 'View'

Any suggestions for how to get past the 2nd set of errors?  Or, is there another approach for unwrapping optionals and evaluating them in SwiftUI?  Really like SwiftUI but can't believe that unwrapping optionals has been a headache!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For such cases I prefer the following approach

```
struct PersonView: View {

    @State private var age: Int? = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Just a test")
            AgeText
        }
    }

    private var AgeText: some View {
        if let age = self.age, age > 0 {
            return Text("Display Age: \(age)")
        } else {
            return Text("Age must be greater than 0!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this method doesn't work if you want to try to provide an `EmptyView()` if the `if let` condition fails. Hence using .map might be more preferable as suggested by @LuLuGaGa

Comment: I am curious why the initial version doesn't work and how this actually solves the problem? Seems like (https://jasonzurita.com/swiftui-if-statement/) covers some of the topics, but it's fairly complex.

Comment: if it's just a matter of a different `String` depending on some condition then it is simpler (both in terms of implementation and in terms of the resulting view hierarchy) to just have a `var` that returns the string depending on the condition and a single `Text` which displays it. e.g. the second solution in [Mojtaba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59508988/1032372).

Answer (score 12):

## Swift 5.3 (Xcode 12)

Now you can use conditional binding right in the view builder:

```
if let age = age {
    if age > 0 {
        Text("Display Age: \(age)")
    } else {
        Text("Age must be greater than 0!")
    }
} else {
    Text("Age not found")
}
```

---

## Refactor (Works in older Swifts too)

You can refactor your code to something more basic like using a function:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Just a test")
        Text(text(age: age)) // Using the function
    }
}

func text(age: Int?) -> String { // Defining the function
    guard let age = age else { return "Age not found" }
    if age > 0 { return "Display Age: \(age)" }
    else { return "Age must be greater than 0!" }
}
```

In general, use functions where you need to cleanup your code. I hope future versions of Swift will support this directly as we expect.

Comment: Thanks, @Mojtaba, for the refactor.  Definitely better organized in addition to getting past the SwiftUI shortcoming of not supporting ```if let``` and ```guard let```.  In the end, I accepted Asperi's solution since it refactored the ```View``` object as well.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to do two check on the value of age: first you are making sure it is not `nil` and then checking that it is greater than 0.
You can use map to get rid of potential `nil` and then a ternary operator to conditionally change the text displayed:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Just a test")
        age.map { Text( $0 > 0 ? "Display Age: \($0)" : "Age must be greater than 0!") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @LuLuGaGa!  Using the ternary operator helped me get past the issue.  I ended up accepting Asperi's solution since it was a more general approach for better code organization as well as getting past SwiftUI's shorting coming of noet supporting ```if let```.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the most readable solution is also the shortest in this case, I used the ternary operator:

```
if let age = age {
    Text(age > 0 ? "Display Age: \(age)" : "Age must be greater than 0!")
} else {
    Text("Age not found")
}
```

I would even take off the else part