# not getting data from dictionary array

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode12.5

this is my array

```
var StudentMenuData = ["house": "Home","person.crop.circle": "Profile","bell": "Notifications","message": "Messages","doc.text": "Syllabus","power": "LogOut"]
```

and here's i am trying to use it

```
for (key,value) in StudentMenuData {
  Text("")
}
```

but its showing this error:

> Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

but same code is working in playground.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - alternative to if let with a conditional closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59508765/swiftui-alternative-to-if-let-with-a-conditional-closure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means what is says: Syntax like `if let` or fast enumeration cannot be used within the rendering area of a SwiftUI view.

A possible way is

```
ForEach(studentMenuData.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
   Text("\(key) -> \(studentMenuData[key]!)")
}
```

Side note: Please name variables with starting lowercase letter

Comment: thank you so much, i also changed the variables name with lowercase. can you also suggest book or something so i can avoid these kind of syntax errors, i searched most of links from google but i didn't found this code example.

Comment: A good source is [100 days of SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui/1) by Hacking with Swift.